# Execute a php script through a url

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php script `hook.php` and is located at `/var/utils` and the content is to print

```
<?php
echo "To be print.";
```

My nginx config is this.

```
server {
  listen 8322;
  server_name docs.com;

  location /hook.php {
    root `/var/utils`;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

When I try to execute it using `docs.com:8322/hook.php` in a browser it won't print anything. When I tried executing it through cli `$ php hook.php` it will print something. Net stat shows that my php-fpm is running in port 9000

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The solution was too add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` in the nginx config

```
server {
  listen 8322;
  server_name docs.com;

  location /hook.php {
    root `/var/utils`;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

[CLOSED]

Comment: Any errors? Did you check your nginx logs? Is php-fpm running on port 9000?

Comment: @Martin I did not find any errors in my nginx logs and fpm is running in port 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was too add fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; in the nginx config

```
server {
  listen 8322;
  server_name docs.com;

  location /hook.php {
    root `/var/utils`;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sitename.com/script.php?f=your_function_name
```

in your `script.php` file;

```
if(function_exists($_GET['f'])) {
  $_GET['f']();
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it won't work. It must be a combination of my nginx config to fix this but I can't figure it out yet.